# Granting DML and DBA Privileges

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a data table called Employees. Say I want to grant only all DML privileges to an user called Shelby. Does this statement work?

```
grant all on employees to shelby;
```

But doesn't that grant a lot more than just DML privileges? What is the proper way to do it?

Now lets say I want to grant only all DBA privileges to Shelby. I wrote the statement:

```
grant dba on employees to shelby;
```

But this returns the error "missing or invalid privilege". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give "system" privileges ("global" privileges)

```
grant dba to shelby;
```

if you want to give "object" privileges (on particular objects, tables, views, etc..)

```
grant select on employees to shelby;
grant insert on employees to shelby;
grant update, alter on employees to shelby;
```